# How can I tell what type of damage an enemy is dealing?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know which damage type monsters inflict?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72815/how-do-i-know-which-damage-type-monsters-inflict)

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell what kind of damage a regular enemy deals (physical, arcane, fire, etc). I know elites have their affixes present below their name but I don't see anything like that on regular enemies.

There are a few enemies who one-hit me (currently, vile swarms in Act 2). I'm wondering if I need to boost some of my resistances but it would be nice to know which ones.

Comment: Just play as a Monk!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot No!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that vile swarms do physical damage. However, I don't think that stacking one specific resistance is such a good idea (although with physical resistance it makes more sense that with others)

Comment: If you're stacking a single resistance, I'd recommend armor.  It acts as straight up all resist.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about those Swarms, I know they are Physical damage.

However, for most others, you can usually tell by the color of the spell that is being used:

Green - poison
Blue - ice/frost
Red - fire
Purple - arcane

Although this is not always 100% true, you can usually guess.

Armor would help all of these stats, but then again it'd take a lot to raise all of these resistances drastically.

What I'm trying to say in a nut shell is:
Are you farming, or making progression? If your farming, boost the resistances you need (i.e. Fire / Physical if you were farming Diablo). Typically I try to balance all of my resistances so I can progress.